# ¿Como detectar que el usuario cambió fecha y hora de su celular en app Android con Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2, broadcastreceiver

Buenos días! Estoy haciendo una aplicación **Android** con **Ionic2** y necesito poder detectar si el usuario realiza un cambio en fecha y/o hora en el sistema.

He investigado que los **Broadcast Receiver** cumplen esta función, pero soy nueva en Ionic y no he podido encontrar la manera de utilizarlos en este `framework`.

¿Alguna idea de que como utilizar el **Broadcast Receiver** con **Ionic**? ¿Otra forma de poder detectar un cambio en el sistema?

Desde ya muy agradecida por su ayuda :)

Comment: Una solución no muy conveniente es guardar la hora y fecha cada vez que el usuario cierre la aplicación, y cuando la vuelva a abrir se debe comparar que la fecha del celular debe ser siempre mayor a la que se había guardado, pero el inconveniente de esto es que solo válida que no haya cambiado la fecha hacia atrás.

Comment: Gracias Jonathan por tu comentario, pero necesito poder detectar este cambio mientras la aplicación esté corriendo.

Comment: Realmente nunca he programado una app, pero tal vez se pueda hacer eso cada vez que el usuario salga de la app (porque para hacer el cambio del hora y fecha tiene que salir), entonces cuando oprima el botón de navegación de atrás ( < ) o el de salir (o) se guarda la fecha.

Comment: Entiendo, el tema es que necesito saber si el usuario cambia fecha/hora en ambas direcciones. Y con esta solución solo puedo detectar un cambio hacia atrás.